# Is there any way to make Chrome include undeclared arguments in `arguments`?

Tags: google-chrome, arguments, google-chrome-devtools

Normally in Javascript, if you reference the "magic" `arguments` variable from inside a function, it will contain all of the arguments passed to the function.  In the Chrome developer tools (on Linux) though, that doesn't happen; if you:

1. Add a `debugger` statement to some function that doesn't have any declared arguments
2. Do something to trigger that function with an argument
3. When Chrome pauses on the `debugger` line, check `arguments` from the console.

You'll see that `arguments` is empty.  Now, this can be fixed easily enough by just declaring arguments on the function; in other words, if you do:

```
function(a,b,c) {
    debugger;
}
```

instead of:

```
function() {
    debugger;
}
```

`arguments` *will* have the arguments (or at least the first three).

However, that really shouldn't be necessary, which leads me to my question: is there any setting I can change, or is there anything else I can do to fix this behavior and just make Chrome put EVERY passed-in argument in to `arguments`, not just the declared ones?

Comment: Possible that the `debugger` statemant breaks your currient scope. Strange anyway.

Comment: That's very possible: if I `console.log(arguments)` rather than use `debugger` then the correct arguments get logged (even if they're undeclared), so this does seem to be specific to `debugger`.

Comment: Also you may say var keep = arguments;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recently has been redone in V8 JavaScript engine. Soon it will make its way into Chrome codebase, which eventually will get into stable release (possibly 28.*.*.* ?).

Comment: Thanks for that info; it's a little annoying to have to wait, but it's great that it's getting fixed :-)